# Difference between CoreceValueCallback and ValidateValueCallback?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, dependency-properties

I know that `CoerceValueCallback` is used to correct a value and that `ValidateValueCallback` will return true or false.  But my question is why we need `ValidatevalueCallback`?  We can simply use `CoerceValueCallback` to validate (using if condition) and correct the value.  Can you give some practical example of when to use coercion vs. validation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Value coercion is basically to change the value, if the the new value is not as system expected. A best example is Slider control. A Slider has both Minimum and Maximum properties. Clearly, it would be a problem if the Maximum value were allowed to fall below the Minimum value. Value coercion is used to prevent this invalid state from occuring.

Validate value, is something that system will only check whether the given input is valid or not. It will throw Argument Exception if value is invalid (if we returned false for such value). For example, we have Age property, and it should be in range of 0 to 120. In case the new value is 500, the system may warn the user instead coercing it to some hardcoded value.

Any way both callbacks are optional and can be used based on the requirement.

Comment: I accept this one(user instead coercing it to some hardcoded value.).But my question is simply we use CoreceValueCallback to Validate and Change the value.Bcoz i read one book they reported Callback order(1.Corece,2.Validate 3.PropertyChanged)

Answer (score 18):

Here are the rules I follow for when to use coercion vs. validation.

**Use [`CoerceValueCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.coercevaluecallback(v=vs.110).aspx) If...**

- You can safely correct a value to be valid without needing to throw an error.
- Your property depends on one or more other dependency properties.
- You need to provide instance-level validation as opposed to class-level validation.
- You allow others to override your validation logic.

**Use [`ValidateValueCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.validatevaluecallback(v=vs.110).aspx) If...**

- You cannot correct a value to be valid.
- You must throw an error if an invalid value is provided.
- You do not want others to override your validation logic.

---

So, it primarily depends on whether or not your property depends on other dependency properties or if you want others to be able to override your validation logic.

Since the `ValidateValueCallback` is not part of the [`PropertyMetadata`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms745795(v=vs.100).aspx#Coerce_Value_Callbacks_and_Property_Changed_Events), inheritors cannot modify the callback through the [`DependencyProperty.OverrideMetadata`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597491(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

Also, since the `ValidateValueCallback` does not provide your [`DependencyObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject(v=vs.110).aspx) as a parameter, you cannot perform advanced validation that depends on other dependency properties.

**Example 1**

Suppose you have `Minimum`, `Maximum`, & `Value` properties.  When any of these change, a `CoerceValueCallback` shoud be used to ensure the other properties are consistent.
That is, `Minmum` <= `Value` <= `Maximum`.

However, assuming these values are doubles, then there are some values that would never make sense, namely `Double.NaN`, `Double.PositiveInfinity`, and `Double.NegativeInfinity`.  Therefore, a `ValidateValueCallback` should be used to verify that the double values are normal, numeric values.

In fact, this is exactly how [`RangeBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase(v=vs.110).aspx) works!

**Example 2**

Suppose you have a `RegexTextBox` control which takes a string containing a regular expression (call it `RegexString`).  If a bad regular expression is provided, then what should be used instead?  It might make sense to coerce it to be a null/empty value, rendering it useless; however, I suggest that this property be validated with a `ValidateValueCallback`.  This is because any error is now thrown at compile-time when designing via the WPF designer.

For this property, there shouldn't be a `CoerceValueCallback` at all.

---

There is a whole lot of information describing how to use these callbacks.
I'd suggest taking a look at the MSDN article, [Dependency Property Callbacks and Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms745795(v=vs.100).aspx#Coerce_Value_Callbacks_and_Property_Changed_Events), for more in-depth knowledge.